# Django: Use makedirs in AWS S3

Tags: python, django

I have code that will automate CSVs and it will create a dir using makedirs with uuid dirname. The code is working on my local machine but not in S3.

I am using an href to download the csv file by passing file_path in context.

views.py

```
def makedirs(path):
try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
return path
```

def ..

```
tmp_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
file_path = 'static/tmp/'+tmp_name+'/'
file_path = makedirs(file_path)
reviews_df.to_csv(file_path+'file_processed.csv', index=False)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you trying to make a directory in s3 using python and write your dataframe as a csv file to the directory?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am using makedirs to do that and the dirname is the tmp_name.

Comment: Ok, I left explanations for the three ways I can think of to accomplish the upload from your local csv file into s3. Let me know in comments if there are further aspects to what you're trying to do that are missed. In particular, I'm not clear where Django is being used in all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python and s3 you need to have permissions to write to the bucket and you need to know the bucket name. Here, I'll assume you have both.

In the AWS python SDK `boto3` you have either a client or a resource-although not all services will have both the most commonly used ones usually do.

```
# s3 client
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file(local_file_name, bucket_name, key_in_s3)
```

The client is usually a lower level aspect of the AWS service and is usually more useful if you are writing some infrastructure code yourself. A resource-usually-is a higher level of abstraction.

```
# s3 resource
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.upload_file(local_file_name, key_in_s3)
```

Also choosing to use a resource does not preclude you from using a client for the same AWS service. You can do so by using the `meta` attribute on the resource. For example to use the client upload way above but using the s3 resource rather than client you would do:

```
# client from resource
s3_resource.meta.client.upload_file(local_file_name, bucket_name, key_in_s3)
```

but usually you wouldn't do that because the bucket under the resource has the option for you already.

Even though the `key_in_s3` doesn't need to be the same as what you have in your local filesystem it is likely a good idea (for your sanity) to use the same value unless you have requirements otherwise.

Here it sounds like your requirement is to have the s3 key be a uuid. If you plan to download the files at a future point and want to avoid the hassle of selecting the application you might want to include the `.csv` extension after the uuid when you upload to s3. Not a requirement from the s3 side though.

Q: How to make a directory?

A: The bucket is really the directory. Inside a bucket, there isn't really a concept of directory in S3. The `/` characters are used to delineate lists of objects in the AWS console and in the AWS CLI but that is more of a convenience. If you want to have that then you can construct it in the code where you write the s3 key. The In other words the way you have your file path and file name in a single string should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to create a dir in S3 before writing the df.to_csv?

Comment: I'll add a comment in the answer at the end to address

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Everything is working now!!!